# Maintain sessions in android

Tags: java, android

How to pass `jwt` token to the secured `api` and get `json` data? I have used this code. I am getting `http` response as unauthorized.

```
String url1 = ("http:/****************/getAllocationsList");

            try{

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(User_Info, MODE_PRIVATE);
            final String token = prefs.getString("username", null);

            System.out.println("token" + token);


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url1);

            String json = "";

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            json = jsonObject.toString();

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

            else

                result = " Did not work! ";

            Log.d("RESULT", result);

             System.out.println("request"+result);
```

Comment: Unauthorized means, you dont have a valid token to access the api url. Check if you're passing proper token value to the header.

Comment: token is correct, i am getting result as Cannot POST /getAllocationsList

Comment: Check your URL as it is GET or POST and then accordingly make call, otherwise provide URL so can give you exact scenario and solution

Comment: @PriyankaAwate why you are using `Deprecated code` like here as i can see `HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();`  first change it.